# How to make snake move by 1 pixel

Tags: logic, game-development

[image: The segment with the larger x position is the snake head.]
The segment with the larger x position is the snake head.

Hello, I want the snake to move by 1 pixel at the time and hence **not** by the size of the grid, what's the ***logic*** of doing so?

I have tried to make the head move by 1 pixel and then move the tail to be at the same position as the segment before it etc. which results in the snake shrinking for obvious reasons (because the segment before the head will be at the old head position, which results in that segment covering the whole head except of 1 pixel).

I have also tried to make the head move by 1 pixel and then move the rest of the body by 1 pixel but if we do so, then when we move the snake up, the head should go up while the body should move to the right/left to get the special "snake movement" but if we do so, we obviously get a gap:

[image]

So, how do I make the snake move in its special way by 1 pixel at the time ?